# Upload file use request module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I have a function upload file:

```
handleUpload: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = this.refs.fileupload.getDOMNode().files; //get all the files to be upload.
    if (files.hasOwnProperty(0) //get the first file.
        && files[0] instanceof File) {

       var formData = new FormData();

       formData.append('fileUpload',
                       files[0]); //append file to be sent to the server.

       formData['fileUpload'] = files[0]

       Service.uploadContact(null,null,formData)
       .then(function(data){
         if (data.statusCode == 0) { //upload success
           this.setState({
             validationmessage: data.message,
             success: true,
             showSpinner: false
           })

           React.findDOMNode(this.refs.fileupload).value = '' //clear upload file.
           this.filterContact_Paging(1); //refresh the contact list.
         } else {
           this.setState({
             validationmessage: data.error, //upload fail error
             success: false,
             showSpinner: false
           })

           React.findDOMNode(this.refs.fileupload).value = '' //clear upload file.
         }
       }, function(_err){
         console.log('err: ', _err)
       })
    }   
},
```

And code process upload use request module:

```
serviceInterface[item.name] = function (params, csrfToken, formData) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       var token = storage.get('token') || '',
         request_params = {
           url: CONFIG.apiPath + item.path,
           method: item.method,
           crossOrigin: true,
           withCredentials: false,
           json: true,
           headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
         };

       //This is where you append form data and in most cases for file upload.
       if (formData) {
         request_params['formData'] = formData;
       }

       //This is a cross site reference token
       if (csrfToken) {
         headers['x-csrf-token'] = csrfToken.token;
         headers['x-csrf-sec'] = csrfToken.secret;
       }

       //This is where you determine post/get to send the data through body or querystring.
       if (item.method == 'GET') {
         request_params['qs'] = params;
       } else {
         request_params['body'] = params;
       }

       request(request_params, function (error, response, body) {
         if (error) {
           return reject(error);
         }

         if (response.statusCode === 418) {
           return reject(body);
         }

         return resolve(body);
       });
     });   
};
```

But when I run code, it throw a error:
TypeError: self._form.on is not a function

Comment: Can you show full error message?

Comment: it is an error in file request.js:
 self._form.on('error', function(err) {
    err.message = 'form-data: ' + err.message
    self.emit('error', err)
    self.abort()
  })

Comment: it same issuse in this link : https://github.com/request/request/issues/1961

but when i fix such it throw an other error at: self._form.on('error', self.onError.bind(self))

Comment: Well you could use some other module instead. Like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-request